# Classical capacity of the quantum bitflip channel

Tags: resource-request, channel-capacity

I'm looking for references or a derivation for the classical capacity of the quantum bitflip channel,
$$\mathcal{N}(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + pX\rho X.$$

Or if this is not known, are some other quantities like the Holevo information available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical capacity of the quantum bitflip channel is 1.

The states $|+\rangle\langle+|$ and $|-\rangle\langle-|$ are invariant under bitflip channel.

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the bitflip map.

$$
\therefore\mathcal{N}(|+\rangle\langle+|) = (1-p)|+\rangle\langle+| + pX|+\rangle\langle+|X =(1-p)|+\rangle\langle+| + p|+\rangle\langle+|=|+\rangle\langle+|\,.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\mathcal{N}(|-\rangle\langle-|) = |-\rangle\langle-|\,.
$$
Therefore, you can encode your 0 and 1 into $|+\rangle\langle+|$ & $|-\rangle\langle-|$ respectively and achieve the classical capacity of 1 since you can always send 1-bit of information per channel usage regardless of the presence of bitflip noise.